# Error con funcion FILTER de Google Sheets

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo, formulas

estoy siguiendo un ejemplo de una pagina de Google para la Función FILTER y recibo un ERROR pero hago exactamente lo mismo de los ejemplo, o por lo menos eso creo, a ver si elguien me orienta.

Acá dejo el enlace de la Hoja: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YNO5hRgIam6UeEQhXvd7pJaiLhGW0vSValbqXjodqYU/edit?usp=sharing

Y el del Ejemplo:
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que tu hoja de cálculo está configurada para utilizar punto y coma (;) como separador de parámetros de la función pero en su lugar usaste coma  (,).

Para resolver, cambia la coma (,) por punto y coma (;)